# Why it is said to recite any mantra 108 times?

Tags: mantras, sadhana

In order to complete any prayer or sadhana, it is said to repeat any mantra for at least 108 times ? What is the significance and importance of that ?

Answer (score 1):

It is taken from [here](https://raga.raksham.com/2019/02/26/5-reasons-of-chanting-mantras-108-times/).

> 1.There are 9 planets in the solar system and 12 zodiac sign which are moving on 9 planets. So 9 X 12=108.This is simple says that one should
>   chant no 108 for respecting the solar system .
>
> 2.In Sanatan Dharma there are 27 stars and each star has four Pada or Padas. So 27 X 4=108.So 108 has long been considered a sacred number
>   in Hinduism and yoga.
>
> 3.Diameter of the Sun is 864327 miles and the Diameter of the moon is 2159 miles. If you multiply the diameter of Sun and Moon with 108 then
>   you will find the distance of Sun and moon from the earth.
>
> 4.The number 108 represent the ultimate reality of the universes. The number 1 denotes that one thing and 0 denotes that nothing and 8
>   denotes everything or infinity.
>
> 5.There are 54 letters in Sanskrit alphabet.Each has masculine and feminine,Shiva is the masculine and Sakti is the feminine. So it 54 X
>   2=108.In some other arguments that Atman of human beings goes through
>   108 stages on its journey. There are 108 upanishads for which it is
>   beneficial to chant 108 times